# How do I restart wlan0 with the static ip instead of a dynamic ip?

Tags: linux, bash, network-programming, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Wheezy. The `/etc/network/interfaces` is set up to give the Pi a static ip on start up. However, when connection is dropped the Pi won't re-establish a connection automatically. I have a script that restarts wlan0. However, the Raspberry Pi has a different ip address than the static ip given to it. This breaks the port forwarding I’ve done to access the Pi from outside the network.

It looks as if my interfaces is not set up quite right. The Pi can be accessed from two ip addresses within the network, one is the static address I defined while the other is not. When wlan0 is restarted, a dynamic ip address is given to the Pi, but not the static address.

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
     auto lo
     iface lo inet loopback

     auto eth0
     allow-hotplug eth0
     iface eth0 inet manual

     auto wlan0
     allow-hotplug wlan0
     iface wlan0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.11
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 192.168.1.1
     wpa-ssid "ROUTER NAME"
     wpa-psk "PASSWORD"

     auto wlan1
     allow-hotplug wlan1
     iface wlan1 inet manual
     wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Here is the script I'm using to reset wlan0:

```
     #!/bin/bash

     SERVER=192.168.1.1 #Ping the router

     ping -c2 ${SERVER} > /dev/null

     #If the exits status from the ping is not 0 (failed)
     if [$? != 0]
     then
         #Disable wlan0 and re-enable it
         sleep 2
         ifconfig wlan0 down 
         sleep 2
         ifconfig wlan0 up
     fi
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Edit:
After looking around with ideas found in this thread, I found `/etc/init.d/networking restart` does everything I need.So the new script is

```
    #!/bin/bash

    SERVER=192.168.1.1
    ping -c2 ${SERVER} > /dev/null

    if [ $?!=0 ]
    then
        /etc/init.d/networking restart
        echo "Reconnecting!"
    fi
```

Comment: Replace `ifconfig wlan0 down` in your script with `ifdown wlan0` and `ifconfig wlan0 up` with `ifup wlan0`.

Comment: I tried this. The pi will disconnect as expect but not reconnect. It disconnects and reconnects sucessfully the way it is above. The only issue is that the ip address after reconnecting is not the static address (192.168.1.11). When I use `ifup wlan0` the Pi won't reconnect, and I don't have any error messages as I am working on it through SSh. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: What do you see in the `/var/log/messages` after failed `ifup`? It's still a mystery, how your interface is getting different IP address than that which is configured... `ifconfig` simply brings your interface down and up, not running any instructions in the `/etc/network/interfaces`, so your wlan0 retains all ip information which it had before going down. `ifdown/ifup` scripts is the way to go, if you want to configure your interface besides bringing it up. Please check the logs.

Comment: when running the script with `ifdown/ifup` these lines are added to `var/log/messages`:  `Dec 21 18:55:25 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2878.536225] wlan0: deauthenticating from 6c:b0:ce:00:cf:bd by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)` 
`Dec 21 18:55:25 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2878.628417] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain`  This tells me that it is disconnecting but there is nothing about reconnecting, which is what I'm experiencing. In order to reconnect, I need to remove and add the USB wifi dongle.

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Comment: @NateTheGreat that crda issue is usually caused by corrupt leases under /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.* . The quick fix is to rm /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.* .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked around a bit and it seems you may be able to make sure it is set in your wifi script after `ifconfig wlan0 up` (I've also had to implement such a script on every raspberry pi setup I've ever made due to wifi inconsistencies)

```
if [$? != 0]
     then
         #Disable wlan0 and re-enable it
         sleep 2
         ifconfig wlan0 down 
         sleep 2
         ifconfig wlan0 up
         ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.11
     fi
```

Though it should be noted that I personally have never set up a static ip on a pi, I use a reverse tunneling service so I never have to worry about port forwarding. My answer references this answer from the raspberrypi stackexchange site.
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9678/static-ip-failing-for-wlan0

Let me know if that helps otherwise I can dig deeper into it.

According to feedback from the asker, the `/etc/init.d/networking restart` was the answer, read comments below.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have any effect. The pi is still has an ip address that is not 192.168.1.11. Thanks for the thought though.

Comment: I'll run some experiments later when I'm home and get back to you

Comment: Looks as if there is a command that calls `/etc/network/interfaces`. `/etc/init.d/networking restart` sets everything back to the way `/etc/network/interfaces` sets everything up. I'll see if this can re-establish a connection tonight, when there are less devices relying on the network. Best case scenario, the `restart` command establishes a connection. Worst case scenario, I run it at the end of the script I posted and it fixes the issues with the ip addresses I've been having. Thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem, let me know if that works out for you, it's something I may need to implement in the future.

Comment: `/etc/init.d/networking restart` does exactly as I need. It re-esablishes networking with the static ip, as well as that extra ip (although I'm not too concerned about that). No need to use `ifdown/ifup` or `ifconfig <device> down/up` in the script.

Comment: Great! thanks for following up with that